# cost for hosting a largish online radio station

Tags: streaming, audio

How much does a connection for an internet radio station that feeds maybe a 100K users cost to the company that provides it? Do you have to be in a special location to get such an upload capability or do you send it to broadcasting company, and if so how much would that cost?

Answer (score 2):

A better way would be to stream to a web server which then streams it to everyone.  You can then use any home connection and have a wide variety of web hosts available.

Comment: thanks, and any idea about the cost to such a web server?